# How to clear Autocomplete field using a button

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Know how do I understand the selection field of a v-autocomplete by assigning it to a button.

The memory is even cleared, but the selection field is still the selected item.
Can anyone help me in this case? Any solution?

[image: button field texts]

```
<Autocomplete
        @getItemSelecionado="receberAno"
        :items="anos"
        label="Ano"
        placeholder="Selecione um ano"
      />

clear() {
      this.anoSelecionado = "";
      this.areaSelecionada = "";
      this.instituicaoSelecionada = "";
      this.tituloSelecionado = "";
      this.orientadorSelecionado = "";
      this.pesquisadorSelecionado = "";
      this.filtros = {};
    },
```

The Autocomplete used above is a component created from the v-autocomplete below:

```
<template>
<v-autocomplete
    :label="label"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    v-model="select"
    :items="items"
    :item-text="itemText"
    :disabled="disable"
    outlined
    :multiple="multiple"
    :chips="chips"
    flat
    filled
    color="#277049"
    clearable
  >
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "AutocompleteAtom",
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
    },
    itemText: {
      type: String,
    },
    disable: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    multiple: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    chips: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      select: null,
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign the v-model to variable "select" in component data.

And the value of this input is storage only in this child component. You can pass it to parent component by @onChange event and $emit.

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

You can also assign prop as a v-model and passing it from parent component.

For example:

```
    <Autocomplete
        @getItemSelecionado="receberAno"
        :items="anos"
        :value="value"
        label="Ano"
        placeholder="Selecione um ano"
      />
```